# Can't build project because of and undeletable .exe file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Recently I started to use Visual Studio 2022 to develop Web Applications (in .NET 6.0). Initially everything was fine but since the last week the program sometimes hangs during the building process and the only way to stop it is to close MSBuild.exe from Task Manager. If I try to rebuild, it will hang again.

I turned on the detailed logging and read the console looking for answers. These are the last lines it printed before it stopped:

*Building target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectory" completely.

1>  Input file "C:...obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\apphost.exe" is newer than output file "bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\EmployeeCheckSystem.exe".

1>  Task "Copy"

1>    Task Parameter:DestinationFiles=bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\EmployeeCheckSystem.exe

1>    Task Parameter:SourceFiles=C:...obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\apphost.exe

1>    Task Parameter:OverwriteReadOnlyFiles=False

1>    Copying file from "C:...obj\Debug\net6.0-windows\apphost.exe" to "C:...bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\EmployeeCheckSystem.exe".*

Then I tried to delete EmployeeCheckSystem.exe but I was unable, even with admin rights; the file doesn't even show a message, it simply doesn't go away. So I am forced to reboot my computer, which lets me delete the file and build /run my project again. For clarification, I can rebuild without delete the file, with the reboot is enough. Also, the problem seems to affect only one project at a time.

Looking in this site for a solution I stumble with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344949/exe-file-created-from-build-is-impossible-to-delete). It has a lot in common with my case, except for the .net version (7 instead of 6). Still I ask my own question because the previous one doesn't have an real solution. Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: We (2 persons) have the same issue and have been running an internal IT ticket to try and figure out what is going on. The initial investigations from my colleague was that one of the anti-virus products we run was at fault - at this point I'm not sure.

What anti-virus are you running?

Some conclusions so far - this happens on both .net 6 and 7 projects. It also happens with just MSBuild. Some days it works fine - other days I have rebooted my PC 10+ times which is ofc. very disruptive. ><

Comment: @Reonekot So far I have not found a definitive solution, but I found out that closing the database manager (SQL developer in my case) and the web browser used to open the web app let me delete the executable and therefore rebuild my app without rebooting.